# WAS 9 - JSF 2.1 - Icefaces 3.3.0

Tags: jsf, websphere, icefaces, myfaces, was

is it possible to use JSF 2.1/Icefaces 3.3.0 implementation with Websphere 9?

In that case, have you any guide/tutorial that can help me?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although WebSphere 9 provides an EE7 runtime (that is JSF 2.2), JSF 2.1 and ICEfaces 3.3.0 should work. You need to follow IBM's instructions [1] for using a "third-party JSF implementation": provide the JSF 2.1 implementation and its dependencies, as well as ICEfaces, in an isolated shared library.  The caveat with this approach is that WebSphere does not support CDI+JSF integration for this scenario.

[1] https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_9.0.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/tweb_jsf22.html